# WPF navigation page memory usage

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a client using WPF's navigation window, where the app enters the next page by calling

```
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new MyNextPage());
```

This app runs on a hand-held device with limited memory. I am curious how long would those `new MyNextPages()` live after a user leaves that page? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562054/should-i-navigate-to-a-relative-uri-or-navigate-to-a-new-instance-of-a-page-in) says those pages are kept alive, which worries me because I am doing a `new NextPage()` for every single navigation (backward or forward).

Is using

```
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MyNextPage.xaml",UriKind.Relative))
```

better? why?

Note: I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864383/wpf-navigate-form-to-form), but my situation is different in which my MainWindow is a NavigationWindow and it navigates to Pages.